# SQL Merge Replication - Filter Sets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, filtering, merge-replication

I have a "working" Replication Set in SQL 2005 that we use in house to our users at remote branches on SQL Express 2005.  I want to apply a filter to our biggest Set to help minimize the bandwidth impact.  What I am asking is what considerations do I need to take into account before throwing a filter on there.  Will it cause any issues I should be aware of?  Does it affect compression adversely.  Will everyone need to reinitialize after applying it?

Any heads up or insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

### EDIT

Here is a snapshot showing where the Compression setting is that I am talking about.
[image: SQL 2005 Compression Setting]

Also, I could include a shot of the zipped snapshots if necessary.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which version of SQL ? You speak about compression, so i guess it's 2008 ?

Comment: nope, 2005, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What compression are you using?  SQL 2005 doesn't support compression.

The way the row filtering works is that when the snapshot is taken a WHERE clause is put on the select statement that BCP uses to export the data.  When the data is being transfered the data is run against the filter and if it matches the filter then the data is transmitted.  If the data doesn't match the filter it is not transmatted to the subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this.  I have edited my post to include a screenshot of the compression setting.

Comment: That compression is on the snapshot only.  After the snapshot is created the exported files are compressed into a Microsoft CAB file.  If you are using pull replication this can be helpful.  For push replication is won't do anything for you.  The compression is not used in the normal moving of data after the snapshot has been applied.  After you apply the filter all the subscribers will need to be reinitialized.